# How to get next 9am in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to reset a timer every 24 hours at a specific time that is at 9am instead of midnight. The following gives the next midnight. Now how to get the next 9am?

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(24,0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you mean 9 a.m. *the next day*, regardless of whether it's currently before or after 9 a.m., interestingly you do it the same way, just add 9 to 24 to make 33 (no, really):

```js
function setNextDay9(dt) {
  dt.setHours(33, 0, 0, 0);
}

// Test with start time before 9 a.m.
var d1 = new Date(2018, 10, 7, 7);
console.log("before", d1.toISOString());
setNextDay9(d1);
console.log("after ", d1.toISOString());

// Test with start time after 9 a.m.
var d2 = new Date(2018, 10, 7, 11);
console.log("before", d2.toISOString());
setNextDay9(d2);
console.log("after ", d2.toISOString());
```

JavaScript's `Date` object handles rollover that way (per spec).

If you mean the next 9 a.m. (same day if before 9 a.m., next day if after), you need to branch:

```js
function setNext9(dt) {
  dt.setHours(dt.getHours() < 9 ? 9 : 33);
}

// Test with start time before 9 a.m.
var d1 = new Date(2018, 10, 7, 7);
console.log("before", d1.toISOString());
setNext9(d1);
console.log("after ", d1.toISOString());

// Test with start time after 9 a.m.
var d2 = new Date(2018, 10, 7, 11);
console.log("before", d2.toISOString());
setNext9(d2);
console.log("after ", d2.toISOString());
```

JavaScript's `Date` object handles rollover that way (per spec).

Comment: I mean next 9 a.m. and not next day 9 a.m.

Comment: @ChrisJake - Ah, for that you need to branch; updated.

Comment: @ChrisJake - I think you have enough above to apply to whatever code you need to apply it to.

Comment: Sorry for asking but I tried and I couldnt get the time between current time and next 9 a.m.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with time, I highly recommend using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/).

`var nineAm = moment().hour(9) // will set the time to 9am`

```
if moment().hour() === 9 {
    //reset time
}
```

Comment: Depending on how much you plan to use it, of course. If this is all he needs, adding 143 KB to his page or project would be overkill

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(); 
d.setHours(9,0,0,0)
let tomorrow = d.setDate(d.getDate() +1)
```

Will return a timestamp to be converted back to a readable date